# Is there a tool to efficiently export a BigQuery table to BigTable?

Tags: file, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Is there a tool to efficiently export a BigQuery table or query result to a BigTable table?

Ideally this would be a single Dataflow program that did a BigQuery query on a table and wrote the results to a BigTable table, with a designated key column, and corresponding column names for all the fields.

Second best would be a dataflow program that takes the output CSV files from a BigQuery export to GCS part files, and loads those into a BigTable table, ideally specifying which is the key and which columns to keep.

Comment: Use a Dataflow pipeline (see link): `BigQueryIO` -> `ParDo` -> `Bigtable`